# Main dialog destroys before command message handler returns

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, user-interface, wtl

My program use a modeless dialog to interact with the user and also has a tray icon.
A user can quit the app immediately by using the tray icon.

```
BOOL OnInitDialog()
{
    init data...
}

void OnDestroy()
{
    destroy data...
}

void OnSomeButton()
{
    CFileDialog dlg;
    ...
    dlg.DoModal(m_hWnd));
    access data...
    ...
}

void OnMenuExit()
{
    DestroyWindow();
}
```

The problem is that when I popup a modal dialog(`OnSomeButton`), and then quit using the tray icon menu, the main dialog is destroyed first, and then the modal one returns, trying to access some invalid data, causing a crash.

I know i can add some check code before accessing the data, but is there any other way? 
Is there any way to ensure OnSomeButton() returns before window destroy?

Comment: Why is the data in question invalid?  If the application is exiting anyway, there's no need to (for example) free allocated memory.  Restructuring so that the memory in question isn't freed when exiting may solve your problem.

Comment: Even if i don't free the memory, some state data content become invalid since the window has been destroyed, causing unpredictable app behavior...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah.  When you quit from the tray menu, you can send a `WM_CLOSE` or similar message to your modal dialog that causes it to exit.  Even if your main window is destroyed before that `OnSomeButton` returns you will be okay provided the remainder of that function does not access any class internals (member variables etc).  You could ensure this by having the window proc of your modal dialog return an 'abort' code or something when it is closed in this way.

Comment: So you mean that,add an abort code to the modal dialog and when it returns, just check this code and then stop further processing?

Comment: Yep, because the code area for your class lives in one place - you can finish executing that code even after your class object is gone, provided you don't access the object.  The other way you could go is to set a value in the modal dialog's class itself, and test that.  But to do that you must allocate the object on the heap instead of creating it on the stack.  Either way, the main window has to maintain some knowledge of the existence of a modal dialog.  Either store the HWND or store the CDialog pointer.  And watch out for thread contention.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add your own application level code. There is no system support for this issue primarily because there can be so many pecularities that no generic approach is possible.